# How to display json response as information cards in the view (html page)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, json

I am currently displaying a json response in my view of the contents in my database. However, I would like to present it in the form of information cards in my html view. How should I go about it? Any code base for reference?

My json response that I am displaying on html in my view is as follows:

```
{"result":[{"id":"3","username":"Sam","password":"111"},{"id":"4","username":"Harshal","password":"1234"},{"id":"5","username":"Dev","password":"112"},{"id":"6","username":"Lam","password":"113"},{"id":"7","username":"Tim","password":"114"}]}
```

I want it to look something like this

https://bootsnipp.com/tags/card

Comment: Which UI framework do you use?

Comment: @ManUtopiK - I am using Ruby on Rails as my frontend and php codeigniter as my backend

Comment: Ruby on Rails is a server side language!? You're not using Ruby on Rails for your frontend.

Comment: MVC framework of rails and php is being used. I am displaying the results in my views that are in .html.erb format

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `JSON` into `hash` or `OpenStruct`. I suggest you convert it to `OpenStruct`. Then you can use it in view.

```
users_json_string = '{"result":[{"id":"3","username":"Sam","password":"111"},{"id":"4","username":"Harshal","password":"1234"},{"id":"5","username":"Dev","password":"112"},{"id":"6","username":"Lam","password":"113"},{"id":"7","username":"Tim","password":"114"}]}'
```

Then

```
users = JSON.parse(users_json_string, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Now you can do what you want with `users`. Choose one card template. Then create the cards in the loop as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% users.result.each do |user| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
              <h5 class="text-bold"><%= user.username %></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would give me only the usernames as plain text output? I mean it wouldn't be displayed like "username":"Sam"? Also, I want to display all the details as cards, similar to what you see here https://bootsnipp.com/tags/card

Comment: I tried to use the updated code but it's not giving output in the form of cards I am still seeing it one below the other. Also, I included the bootstrap gem in the gem file and did bundle install too